# how could I check programmatically if the who user is trying to buy in-app billing item is its publisher?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When I try to use a in-app billing item its api show that: “The **publisher** cannot purchase this item”

I want to check in my app if the user is myself, a google Play Store user and the publisher of app, to put all inapp billings items free for me, so how could I check programmatically if the who user is trying to buy in-app billing item is its publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A developer cannot purchase anything from herself. To fully test, you will need to create a test account in the Developer Console and then install your app on a device where that is the primary account. There is no other way. See
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html